# Teshuvah and Justice

Tags: repentance-teshuvah

I am confused about the issue of Teshuvah. Is it only for Jews? If not, what is the process like for Gentiles? Who legislates on this?

Another doubt is the dynamics of forgiveness and justice. In Ezekiel 33 it says that the wicked in his wickedness will die but if he does techuvah you will live. What are you referring to? Did he leave Judaism and come back, or did he commit a sin and simply repent? If the second option is the correct one, and as is the question that many say, “God forgives but does not take away the consequence of sin”, now sin would lead to death, he repented he would not die, so there is no consequence, it was completely absorbed. Is techuvah not applicable to cardinal sins such as idolatry, murder and adultery? For if he is going to be killed would techuvah prevent the sentence? If not, would his death be God's forgiveness of sin?

Comment: So much there, I'm not sure this question is focussed enough. Learn all of Hilchot Teshuva by the Rambam, and it will answer most of your questions. Next step would be Shaarei Teshuva by Rabbeinu Yonah. Lubavitch sources also discuss this very incredible mitzva and topic, and explain more of the depths of the idea, eg https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMD-i-qFmkU. But, Teshuva means return to closeness to God, not Judaism (you can't leave Judaism). Day of death is almost impossible to change. Teshuva is possible with all sins. Death is never "forgiveness", but rather, sometimes atonement.

Comment: The point is that Ezekiel treats Techuvah as avoiding capital punishment, is this in the context of a trial or unproven sins? At the time, the Sanhedrin already existed or so the tradition says, so the techuvá would not have the strength to prevent the death of this sinner since idolatry, murder and adultery were the death penalty, regardless of whether he repented, only if they were sins that never were. proved, so the techuvah they refer to is to prevent what kind of death? Here on earth under the force of law or in a more spiritual context or a future reincarnation?

Comment: It is talking about the fulfilment of the curses, i.e. that the wicked die because of their sins (through calamities, which are Divine decrees).

Comment: So it only applies to unproven sins? Isn't it kind of dangerous to think that calamities fulfill divine decrees? And the children who die involved in it like in a plane crash, some have done evil but others certainly haven't. And there's also the issue that the hands of heaven don't punish anyone before the age of 20 but that would be discussed in a specific question for that.

Comment: During times of prophecy, one of the roles of prophets was to warn individuals about their sins, using knowledge gained through prophecy. Almost all sins committed under the sun occur without any earthly court involvement, and Tanach and the Oral Torah tell us a lot about how the heavenly court deals with things. The topic of theodicy is obviously a huge one. It is a strong Torah principle that (almost) all suffering is the result of sin. See Ezekiel 33:6 for eg! I think your questions are too large for a stack exchange question :)

Comment: Thank you so, I am satisfied with many things you told me, although there are still many doubts, I intend to formulate shorter and more direct questions for a better discussion on this vast topic.

Comment: Great! Sure. You can also start a chat room, if you do let me know and I'll pop in when I can

Comment: On the question, Is it only for Jews? Certainly not, see the story of Yonah and the people of Nineveh.

Comment: 'many say, “God forgives but does not take away the consequence of sin”' I don't know who says that? But aside from sources like the Rambam's Hilchot Teshuvah, just from logic: Sin has two types of impact. One is the damage done in this world, the dead person or the broken window. The other is the damage done to a person's relationship to G-d. Teshuvah can certainly help to fix the second, and that may avert many consequences. The first may be harder to fix, and of course the person must do whatever they can to fix it, and to repair relationships with people. There may still be consequences.

Comment: @MichoelR In the case of Jonah well remembered. The question is, after they repented and destruction was avoided, nothing else would happen as a consequence right? As for people who say that God forgives but does not take away the consequences of sin are based on David and Bathsheba, God forgave David but the child of such an illicit union died and the sword would never be taken from his kingdom.

Comment: @MichoelR “God forgives but does not take away the consequence of sin” might be basd on Kohelet 1:15 "Which is a fault that cannot be rectified" and explanation in Chagiga 9a saying it is talking about incest and mazmer

Comment: If I understand correctly then, sin will only have consequences if it is not punished by an earthly court but by the hands of heaven and if a person does techuvah the consequences of sin are annulled, so the consequence of sin is for the lack of techuvah, so the what happened to Jonah and Nineveh? Did God punish them in some way further even with techuvah? That which seems confusing to me

Comment: @Thales I don't think that's correct. But it depends on what you mean by consequences. Every sin destroys something (and is therefore its own "punishment"), and depending on the severity of the sin, the harder the damage is to undo. Teshuva means reconnecting with God, saying sorry, Him forgiving you. Atonement means fixing the damage. They are connected but definitely separate and have their own rules and it is a big study.